# Code breaks after executing copy statement in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to identify if a worksheet called Books exists, if not I want to duplicate worksheet called Items and rename it to Books. My problem is that after this line, the code snaps out and stops without giving me an error at all.

Comment: Which code, which line?

Answer (score 1):

Qualify the sheets with a workbook reference or use ws_MCAT.

```vb
    Dim i As Long
    If Not ws_McatPrepareExists Then
        With ws_MCAT
            i = .Index
            .Copy After:=.Parent.Sheets(i)   'duplicate the worksheet after the original
            .Parent.Sheets(i + 1).Name = "Mcat_Prepare" 'rename the new worksheet
        End With
    End If
```